# XML TO database Insertions

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i am using a ftp connection to retrieve data from one site and then am storing that data on my server

the imported data is in ZIp format

first am extracting that data and then storing the zip and xml file  on my server 
then the data from  that xml file is stroing in the data base

everything is going fine except the database storage

the data from the XML file is not storing in my DAtabase

Here is my code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","dbname","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$conn = ftp_connect("ftpname") or die("Could not connect");//create connection.

ftp_login($conn,"ftpusername","ftppassword");//login.

$files_list_at_server = ftp_nlist($conn,"/FEEDER/News/Equity Market News/");//list of current files on server.

$files_at_server=array();
foreach($files_list_at_server as $a)
{
array_push($files_at_server,basename($a));//pushing the file names in a array.
}


$current_dir_files = scandir("equitymarketnews");//list the present files in the dir.

$array = array_diff($files_at_server,$current_dir_files);//different files which are on server and not on our folder.

foreach($array as $q)
{
 ftp_get($conn,"equitymarketnews/$q","/FEEDER/News/Equity Market News/$q",FTP_BINARY); //downloads the files.

 $zip = zip_open("equitymarketnews/$q");

   if ($zip)
    {
     while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
      {
       $zname = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);

       if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry))
         {  
          $zip_fs=zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry);
          $zz = zip_entry_read($zip_entry,$zip_fs);

          $z=fopen("equitymarketnews/$zname","w");
          fwrite($z,$zz);
          fclose($z);
        //  $sql1 = "TRUNCATE TABLE `bod`";
        //  mysql_query($sql1);

      $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'equitymarketnews/$zname' INTO TABLE `equitymarketnews` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES STARTING BY '<row>' TERMINATED BY '</row>' (`ByLine`,`StoryId`,`PublishDate`,`Author`,`Category`,`SubCategory`,`TitleLine`,`SubTitleLine`,`StoryMain`,`Flag`)";
                mysql_query($sql);
                echo mysql_error(); 

          zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
         }
 }}
zip_close($zip);
}
ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to store the data in the database?  The rest of the info is kind of superfluous.

Comment: nothing am getting nothing 
i tried to show error by mysql_error()

but nothing showed up